# How to use buttons to toggle image visibility?

Tags: javascript, html, image, function, button

I am trying to have a button make an image appear when you press them, then hide them when you press the same button. (3 different images and 3 different buttons in my code). In the code I make the images appear, but I don't know how to make the same buttons hide the images.

```js
function image1() {
  document.getElementById("image1").src = "image1.jpg";
}

function image2() {
  document.getElementById("image2").src = "image2.jpg";
}

function image3() {
  document.getElementById("image3").src = "image3.jpg";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="image1()">image1</button>
<img src="" id="image1">

<button onclick="image2()">image2</button>
<img src="" id="image2">

<button onclick="image3()">image3</button>
<img src="" id="image3">
```

Comment: it will be more easy with jquery toggle if you want to use jquery.

Comment: Pass `this` as an argument to the functions e.g. `onclick=image1(this)` for starters. This allows you to access the button that was clicked. I would probably use `data` attributes instead of `id` as well. You could also find the closest element to the button clicked.

Comment: You better hide image with `display: none`. Empty/broken links in some browsers provide empty image glyph that looks ugly.

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Comment: Hi @sonjor ! If the answer helped you solving the problem, please mark it as accepted (press the checkmark under the vote buttons). You can accept only one answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
<button onclick="toggle('image1')">image1</button>
<img src="image1.jpg" id="image1">

<button onclick="toggle('image2')">image2</button>
<img src="image2.jpg" id="image2">


function toggle(targetID) {
  var imgElement = document.getElementById(targetID);
  if(imgElement.style.display == "block"){
     imgElement.style.display = "none";
  }else{
     imgElement.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

Maybe like this ?

Comment: Please, avoid posting an answer that consists of code only without explanation, it helps other users that could have the same problem in the future understanding what you did to solve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you wrap the button and image inside sub-containers. When you click the button, get the parent element (wrapper) and toggle a class on it.

```html
<div class="toggle-image">
  <button onclick="toggle(this)">Image 1</button>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" />
</div>
```

A CSS selector will take care of hiding the image.

```css
.toggle-image.hidden img {
  display: none;
}
```

### Full Example

```js
function toggle(button) {
  button.parentElement.classList.toggle('hidden');
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #111;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.toggle-image {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
}

.toggle-image img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 1em;
   box-shadow: 0.25em 0.25em #EEE;
}

.toggle-image.hidden img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle-image">
  <button onclick="toggle(this)">Image 1</button>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" />
</div>
<div class="toggle-image">
  <button onclick="toggle(this)">Image 2</button>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" />
</div>
<div class="toggle-image">
  <button onclick="toggle(this)">Image 3</button>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/500" />
</div>
```

Comment: I think it would be better to apply the `hidden` class on the image itself, not on the container. Brings more clarity that way

Comment: @VoG That seems like more work. Now you have to go up to the parent, and then down to the image and tweak the visibility of that image... If you alter the "state" of the wrapping-container, you handle this much more gracefully with CSS. I could have gone with `inactive` as the "hidden" class name, but that's beside the point. Statefullness outweighs individual element manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const images = [
  'image.jpg',
  'image2.jpg',
  'image3.jpg'
];

const imagesBox = document.getElementById('images-box');

function image(index) {
  imagesBox.innerHTML = '';
  imagesBox.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend' ,`<img src="${images[index]}"/>`);
}
```

```css
button {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #475863;
  color: white;
  margin: 5px;
}
#images-box {
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="image(1)">Button 1</button>
<button onclick="image(2)">Button 2</button>
<button onclick="image(3)">Button 3</button>
<div id="images-box"></div>
```

Comment: Please, avoid posting an answer that consists of code only without explanation, it helps other users that could have the same problem in the future understanding what you did to solve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery. there is a method call `toggle`. it will help a lot.

```
$('#image').toggle()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something below.

```js
function image1() {
  
  document.getElementById("image1").classList.toggle("hideME");

}

function image2() {
   document.getElementById("image2").classList.toggle("hideME");
}

function image3() {
   document.getElementById("image3").classList.toggle("hideME");
}
```

```css
.hideME {
  display : none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="image1()">image1</button>
<img src="image1.jpg" id="image1" class="hideME">

<button onclick="image2()">image2</button>
<img src="image2.jpg" id="image2" class="hideME">

<button onclick="image3()">image3</button>
<img src="image3.jpg" id="image3" class="hideME">
```

Comment: Please, avoid posting an answer that consists of code only without explanation, it helps other users that could have the same problem in the future understanding what you did to solve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using `data-` attributes to bind a button to a specific image id with pure JS and using jQuery.

`data-` attributes can contain any value you like. Using them doesn't limit you to the placement of the elements in DOM-tree. Buttons and images can be wherever you like in the code, and they can still find each other. Unlike using the method that relies on having the same parent. However, I do agree that it is more readable that way, so it is up to you to decide what is more suitable for your situation :)

```js
/* Pure Javascript*/
// Get the buttons that have the data-image-id attribute
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-image-id]');

// Go over each button to attach a click event
buttons.forEach(function(item, index) {

  item.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // Get the value of the data-image-id attribute
    var image_id = event.target.getAttribute('data-image-id');
    
    // Find the image with specific id and toggle the .active class on it
    document.getElementById(image_id).classList.toggle('active');
  });
  
});

/* Using jQuery */
/*
$('button[data-image-id]').click(function(event) {
  var $this = $(event.target);
  var image_id = $this.attr('data-image-id');
  $('#' + image_id).toggleClass('active');
});
*/
```

```css
/* Hide images that do not have the .active class */
img:not(.active) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--
  The value of the data-image-id attribute
  is the same as the id of an image
-->
<button data-image-id="image1">image1</button>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/100/50" id="image1">

<button data-image-id="image2">image2</button>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/101/50" id="image2">

<button data-image-id="image3">image3</button>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/102/50" id="image3">
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to invert element `hidden` property, like :

```html
<span>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('pic1').hidden^=1" style="top: 25px; left:70px; position:absolute;" type="button">Show or Hide</button>
<img hidden id="pic1" width="50px" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mN8Jyn5HwAFPgIhVXO6lgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't change the `src` in order to hide/show the images, that's a logical change, while you want UI/design changes based on a certain logic.

```js
function hideShow(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.style.display = (element.style.display === "none") ? "block" : "none";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="hideShow('image1')">image1</button>
<img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/821849411991044096/lQFa_Vly_400x400.jpg" id="image1" style="display: none;">

<button onclick="hideShow('image2')">image2</button>
<img src="https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/who-is-the-boss-picture-id480585465?s=612x612" id="image2" style="display: none;">

<button onclick="hideShow('image3')">image3</button>
<img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/vader-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/1595961621-il_794xN.2460764659_56ur.jpg?crop=1xw%3A1xh%3Bcenter%2Ctop" id="image3" style="display: none;">
```

You can see that I have used a single `function` and changed the `display` attribute of `style` instead of `src`. The `function` gets an `id`, loads the element identifiable by that (which is an `img`) and if it has a `display` of `none`, then it's set to `block`. Otherwise it's set to `none`.